# Unexpected Recursive Page in php Codeigniter form

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Whenever i click *submit button* within form with blank textfield, my browser url always go to new url that seems to be recursive, here's the form :

[image]

But if this form be **clicked once more**, it will be like this :

[image]

Below are my code :

Controller, **form.php**

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
                array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        /* I want to use this method, instead of index() */
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
                array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }       
    }
}
?>
```

View, **myform.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<form action="<?php base_url();?>form/validate" method="POST">

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I know, it will work fine if i use `public function index()` or in myform.php be like this :

```
<form action="<?php base_url();?>form" method="POST">
```

But i want to use method `validate()` in my form.  Any solution ? Thanks before...

Comment: Check url two time `form` comes!!

Comment: What is your `base_url()`?? in `config.php`??

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = '';` check what you define in your config file

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju in config.php, $config['base_url'] = ' ';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this,

```
<form action="<?php base_url();?>form/validate" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="<?php base_url("form/validate"); ?>" method="POST">
```

Comment: Glad i could help you:)